# How to autofill a cell based on letter in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel document where I make rosters for my small business, I trying to save myself some time with what creating these. When I enter a letter in a cell, I'd like the rest of the cell to fill in (e.g. O fills the cell with OPEN, C fills the cell with CLOSE, X fills the cell with OFF, etc)

Is there any way of achieving this?

I have not yet tried much and Google has proven rather unhelpful

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with

`File -> Options -> Proofing -> AutoCorrect Options...`

The letters are case sensitives.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To replace a letter with a worth that starts with a different letter, e.g. X with OFF, you would need to use macros. If you have no familiarity with macros, you'd be better off hiring a coder on a task-website to help you with this project.

If you can come up with a list of words that each start with a unique letter, e.g.
OPEN,CLOSE,AWAY instead of OPEN,CLOSE,OFF then you can perform this very easily using data validation.

Just select the range of cells where you want this autofill behaviour to occur. Then go to the Data ribbon and select Data Validation.

[image]

Change the "Allow" setting to "List" and enter your list as comma separated values in the "Source" box without any spaces between the words.

Then, as soon as you type the first letter of any these words in a cell, it will automatically suggest the rest of the matching word and you can just press enter to accept the suggestion and move to the next cell.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Excel has limited autofill capacity. It works within the same column. If you entered once a text string anywhere in the column, next time you start typing in the same column Excel will offer you to autofill, as long as you type the same letters in the same order.

Data Validation as suggested before can restrict your options and even offer a drop down list in cell. Whether or not this is convenient for you, you should try and see for yourself and decide.

If you want to preprocess a whole lot of partial strings typed before, I suggest you use Edit->Replace menu command. The only excel formula per your tag that can help you will be `REPLACE()` but it does not run automatically and will require another column.